# Cameras with opposite positions

Tags: python, camera, quaternion

I have a series of camera data, including the quaternion and position. When I create cameras, I found the position of all the cameras are in the opposite direction (The starting point and the ending point of the camera are opposite.)
[image]
[image]

The code that I use to create cameras is as follows and I add some of the data:

```
import numpy as np
import bpy

cam_data =[[-0.36476696823262345,0.023234429944508573,0.9238808623371452,0.11335507204667462,0.2643092436312764,-0.4627744163606162,4.525118487931772],
[-0.4054905199050235,0.035179478568114673,0.907024207991793,0.1079209371331166,0.3021461539009758,-0.44963208708908553,4.487193496243884],
[-0.44498629984439203,0.04694216063393536,0.8884523859473807,0.10215666600971764,0.3332381314236629,-0.43841177815187343,4.451058213992128],
[-0.4832757412383735,0.058705124977594836,0.868181639171128,0.09622321776992783,0.352540727853317,-0.4311898509770609,4.429843633647341],
[0.5201021779848836,-0.07003897699314113,-0.8464516703174265,-0.09004352266528506,0.3930999979872887,-0.4424100719537798,4.410415094718175],
[0.5554693178653287,-0.08129322321703367,-0.8233838408314181,-0.08297167846267772,0.40584591614055615,-0.44363835361054604,4.388432867705031],
[0.5897283310379344,-0.09242303827379236,-0.7987411860896823,-0.07543868511248913,0.40995873430639507,-0.4419034964054014,4.399626434833313],
[0.6230463233241476,-0.10311904020592387,-0.7723899864702667,-0.06777500527283144,0.4520027034475605,-0.44307975764642865,4.384405638423042],
[0.6549552499532656,-0.11369192223505492,-0.744668211978308,-0.0598082055088044,0.4785516086468784,-0.43684379155905334,4.330680113823206],
[0.685747771018359,-0.12458970645605517,-0.7152620247201971,-0.051260468020791476,0.49486879398471434,-0.44356999715487405,4.278724334858849],
[0.992426281686812,-0.0003958889474642249,-0.10747556558482971,-0.05948883501507541,-0.048720473486560875,-0.026204646129485094,2.8004058427698255],
[0.7153304814243133,-0.1351693897161802,-0.6842630762520066,-0.04260963397116011,0.5124225975959944,-0.4398810005707978,4.222826851917687],
[0.743259864382181,-0.14553128750886044,-0.6521195911231592,-0.03354783492207826,0.5086493021211627,-0.426523916034227,4.169771178687921],
[0.7699112067584281,-0.1559348439141461,-0.6183209857950522,-0.024499320127029604,0.48254201014524306,-0.38492033113053054,4.1412334139346845],
[0.7949627817243883,-0.16648883893805885,-0.5831611416967674,-0.015450728041178766,0.49539618281299447,-0.3711412052525336,4.111542476387624],
[0.8186352513004845,-0.17665337151331445,-0.5464313725570424,-0.006531978765913227,0.52340395014592,-0.3682745741918809,4.062152228676568],
[0.8405854496069631,-0.1870466858975028,-0.508354472267147,0.0023172677469452648,0.5614865636491215,-0.3672916155074743,3.978781497464174]]
cam_quaternion = np.asarray([d[:4] for d in cam_data])
cam_position = np.asarray([d[4:] for d in cam_data])

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

scn = bpy.context.scene
for i in range(len(cam_position)):
    cam = bpy.data.cameras.new(name=f"cam_{i}")
    cam_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(f"cam_{i}", cam)
    cam_obj.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
    
    cam_obj.location = cam_position[i]
    cam_obj.rotation_quaternion[0] = cam_quaternion[i][0]
    cam_obj.rotation_quaternion[1] = cam_quaternion[i][1]
    cam_obj.rotation_quaternion[2] = cam_quaternion[i][2]
    cam_obj.rotation_quaternion[3] = cam_quaternion[i][3]
    scn.collection.objects.link(cam_obj)
    
bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath="scene_with_cameras.glb", export_cameras=True)
```

I don't know if the quaternion in Blender is different. I hope that I can get some help. Thanks！

Comment: Starting rotation or the axis direction might be different. It's not really clear how "opposite" the direction is from what you have written. Is it completely inverted including up direction? Is it just rotated 180° around Y camera axis?.. You just need to transform the camera somehow depending on what you need.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't express myself clearly. What I meant was that the starting point and the ending point of the camera are opposite, and what I expected was that they should switch positions.

Comment: Still not clear. Only you know what you need, only you can figure this out. see: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Quaternion.rotate